# read xml from local iPhone bundle

Tags: xml, xcode

I'm using the following code to read an xml from my server and its working 100%

I need to read the same xml from my app bundle, so what I will change in this function to accomplish my goal?

```
-(void)openXML {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain/data.xml"];    
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
con release];
myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `NSBundle` class to access your app's bundled resources.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"xml"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; //here you have to pass the filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will

NSString *pathStr = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.xml"];
    NSData *dataXml = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathStr]];